# Regular Expression to match underscores not surrounded by brackets?

Tags: regex

Can anyone suggest a regex to match the underscore in the following examples:

```
test_test
test[_test
test_]
```

But NOT match this:

```
test[_]test
```

This is using the .Net Regular Expression library. I'm using this RegEx tester to check:

http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx

Comment: Another tester you might find useful if you are working with .NET is www.lastdomainnameonearth.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
_[^\]]|[^[]_
```

It consists of an alternation of `_[^\]]` (underscore and not `]`) and `[^[]_` (not `[` and underscore).

Or if you want to use look-around assertions to really match just the underscore and not surrounding characters:

```
_(?=[^\]])|_(?<=[^[]_)
```

This matches any underscore that is not followed by a `]` (`(?=[^\]])`, positive look-ahead) or any underscore that is not preceded by a `[` (`(?<=[^[]_)`, negative look-behind). And this can be combined to:

```
_(?:(?=[^\]])|(?<=[^[]_))
```

Comment: This is close, except it's matching an extra character, and not just the underscore.

I tried modifying it to use lookahead, but it doesn't work in all situations.

_(?=[^\]])|(?=[^[])_

Comment: Tested with string: "test[_]test [_test test[_test test_]test test_] test_test". Found 3 matches, should find 5.

Comment: @Moskie: You would need a look-behind assertion in the latter case.

Comment: I think that does it: _(?=[^\]])|(?<=[^[])_

Comment: @Moskie: It would be better to use `_(?=[^\]])|_(?<=_[^[])` instead.

Comment: I meant `_(?=[^\]])|_(?<=[^[]_)`.

Comment: Cool, I think that's the one. I'll give you the credit, but I'd suggest you modify your answer to have that last regex.

Answer (score 2):

```
_(?!\](?<=\[_\]))
```

If the underscore isn't followed by a closing bracket, the negative lookahead succeeds immediately.  Otherwise, it does a lookbehind to find out if the underscore is also *preceded* by an opening bracket.  You can replace the "_]" with dots to make it clear that you're only interested in the opening bracket this time:

```
_(?!\](?<=\[..))
```

You can do the lookbehind first if you want:

```
_(?<!\[_(?=\]))
```

The important thing is that the second lookaround has to be nested within the first one in order to achieve the "`NOT (x AND y)`" semantics.

Testing it in EditPad Pro, it matches the underscore in all but the last of these strings:

```
test_test
test[_test
test_]
_]Test
Test[_
test[_]test
```

EDIT: here's an easier-to-read version:

```
(?<!\[)_|_(?!\])
```

What I like about the nested-lookaround version is that it doesn't do anything until it actually finds an underscore.  Unless the regex engine is smart enough optimize it away, this "`(NOT x) OR (NOT y)`" version will do a negative lookbehind at every single position.

Comment: Tested with string: "test[_]test [_test test[_test test_]test test_] test_test". Found 0 results, should find 5.

Comment: I've tested it in .NET and Java and got the same result: the first five strings match and the last one doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about .Net but the regex would be composed of two parts, one matching any character except a bracket followed by an underscore and the other one vice versa:

```
[^\[](_)|(_)[^\]]
```

Edit: Just noticed that you need to add the cases where the underscore is in the beginning or the end:

```
[^\[](_)|(_)[^\]]|^_|_$
```

Comment: Didn't work for : test[_test

(I'm using the RegEx tester here to test: http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx)

Comment: hi Moskie.. without any options checked.. this regex matches underscore in the "test[_test" string

Answer (score 1):

((?|(?!]))

which uses negative lookahead/behind (rather than positive lookahead/behind and excluded characters).

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
^.*(\[_[^\]])|([^\[]_\])|([^\[]_[^\]]).*$
```

**EDIT:** Now handles

```
test_test
```

Not tested, but read: Any string of characters followed by **either** `[_` then any character *but* `]` **or** any character *but* `[` then `_]`

Note, this might fail for cases like

```
_]Test
Test[_
```

I don't know if that's a problem for you?

Tested successfully with all your examples